# Evolution on Trusty new mail composition, insert items greyed

Tags: email, evolution

When composing a new email, **image**, **link**, **rule** and **tab** are greyed out. While the message body has focus, dragging and dropping or copying and pasting a `*.jpg` results in an attachment rather than a displayed picture.

How can I enable **insert image** etc?

Answer (score 1):

It was set to **plain text**. Selecting **format messages in html** sorted it.